# How can I Navigate to a link after login using ComObject?

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, comobject

How can I navigate to a subsite using a ComObject

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$woop=New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$woop.Visible= $true 
$woop.Navigate("Link")
Start-Sleep 5;
$woop.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("Username-ID").value=$username 
$woop.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("Password-ID").value=$password 
$woop.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("Loggin Button").Click()
Start-Sleep 20 #20 Second timer to wait for the page to fully load
$woop.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("NewSiteContent-ID").Click()
```

This Code works like a charm for me and takes me to the new subsite.
However after I log in to the Site, I can't ***.Navigate*** to this new Site with the ComObject since I don't have the session stored anywhere.

My question: does this problem even have a solution without using ***Invoke Request***?

I found a very good guide for this whole topic [here](https://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2016/9/25/powershell-getting-started-controlling-internet-explorer)

at the end of this Website the user shows possible things one could do like so:

*Now that we're logged in, we could:
Set the $currentDocument variable to $ieObject.Document as the value is now different since a new page has been loaded.
Parse out information we need by exploring the webpage.
Automate looking for a specific post*

But for some reason I cant produce this step.
I get the same Error every time:
**You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression**

My guesses, it cant reach the ID tag since the ComObject is still at the old Login Website since I didn't navigate to the new Link it provides after logging into the Site.

Any solutions/ideas?

**Update 1.)**

You can show with
`ComObjectName.Windows()`
the status of you're ComObject.
I saw that both the LocationURL and the LocationName points to the (login successful session) subsite after login.
Meaning the code of refreshing you're ComObject with the new Site worked.

**example**: `$currentdocument = $woop.document`

Comment: You say *But for some reason I cant produce this step*, is there any error showing when you do the steps according to the article? Besides, can you click a link/button to navigate to the subsite after login? It could be better if you can provide the link of the website so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: I cant give you the link.
Let me update the Question give me a second

Comment: @YuZhou I updated the error and the Code
Pls check out the Code and the end of this Thread/question
Thanks for checking out my Problem and thanks for you're input/help =)

Comment: In the article, it says *It's also good to always refresh your $currentDocument variable after a button click / page load. * Can you please store the current document in variable and refresh it after login like this: `$currentDocument = $woop.Document`? Then try to click the subsite link like this: `$currentDocument.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("NewSiteContent-ID").Click()`.

Comment: @YuZhou Hi. Thanks for the quick reply. I tried to reproduce this. However I get the same error msg: **"you can not call a method on a null-valued expression"** .
When I try to make a new Comobject and give the new one the values of the old one it give me the same error msg

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue when I try to login and redirect websites using PowerShell. It's hard to debug without reproduction. The error seems to mean you use an undeclared (null) variable. You can check if the `NewSiteContent-ID` is right and if the element is in an iframe.

Comment: @YuZhou Hi, thanks for youre awnser. The ID tag is definitely correct. Let me check if its an iframe

Comment: @YuZhou its in 2 HTML tags. Each HTML tag has 1 Iframe.
Meaning the ID wich I have to enter is within 2 Iframes and 1 Section Tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the point. You can't reach the element directly in an iframe. You need to get the iframe first, then use `contentWindow.document` to get the elements in the iframe.

For example, you can use the code below to reach an element in an iframe:

```
$ie.document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document.getElementById('elementId').
```

You can change the code according to your actual situation.

**Reference link:**

(1) [HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

(2) [Accessing a document's IFRAME via Powershell](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f76760d6-aec0-420e-8e1e-af4aad7f1e56/accessing-a-documents-iframe-via-powershell?forum=iewebdevelopment)

Comment: Thank you for youre help =).
Il try to play around with this code for a while. Right now I'm getting some Exeption from HRESULT errors. However If I code this correctly then il probably get access to the elementID.
Thank you for you're help =)

Comment: Hello Yu Zhou, I currently face a new problem with this code. 
I thought why not post it and get you're input if you have time.
My Code right now looks like this:
`$currentdocument.documentElement.getElementByID('webiFrame')[1].contentWindow.document.getElementById('__button12').Click()`


Currently I'm getting the error "Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'getElementByID'

Comment: @NiklasPesthy I suggest that you can still use `IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that already a couple of days ago.
`$currentdocument.documentElement.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('webiFrame')[1].contentWindow.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID('__button12').Click()`
When I tried that it threw this error:
"Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID'."

Comment: If I use exactly this code: `$currentdocument.document.getElementById('webiFrame')[1].contentWindow.document.getElementById('__button12').Click()`

I get the error: Exeption from HRESLT: 0x800A01B6

Comment: I'm confused why you use this: `getElementById('webiFrame')[1]`. Id should be unique in a page. Does the page have several elements with the same `webiFrame` id?

Comment: Oh. No it doesent have multiple webiFrame id`s.
I thought I need [1] array counter 1 to access the second Iframe.
Since webiFrame is within another Iframe

Comment: Almost everything I try throughs an error with this code.
If I only use 

`$currentdocument = $woop.document
$currentdocument.getElementById('webiFrame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('__button12').Click()`
It throughs the good old classic "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error

Comment: If it's the second iframe, you can try to use something like this: `$currentdocument.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[1].contentWindow`. It's hard for me to debug without the html code of the webpage.

Comment: If the first iframe name is different than the second one. Do I still have to iterate through to position '[1]' ?

Comment: My current code is $currentdocument.getElementById('webiFrame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('__button12').Click() Although im getting Exception form HRESULT: 0x800A138A error. I don't think you can help me further since you don't have the sourcecode

Comment: I will use a workaround for now accessing the subpage after login and navigating through the content using System.Windows.Forms. with keystrokes and mouseclicks